# Loading a popup each x visitors of the webpage

Tags: jquery, random, popup, onload-event, bpopup

I'm searching some help to find the better way / script for my special goal.

**How I can load a popup each x visitors of my webpage ?**

My idea is to be able to load a popup each x visitors on a webpage.
This popup will contain randomly a text between a list.

Actually I founded something for the random popup like a "tip" list style, but I'm stucked with the "load each x visitors"

I prefer to use jquery or javascript, and I don't know if that's possible, but I will try to do that with [this jquery one](http://dinbror.dk/bpopup/)

So if someone can give me a trick or a way to search after that, that's will be really fine :)

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean visits?  Or visitors?  If you mean visitors, this will require something on the back end.

Comment: javascript runs on the client, so its not going to keep track across multiple users serverside. You need to have your server code (php/asp/etc) track this.

Answer (score 1):

How you actually show the popup is pretty irrelevant, the challenge is counting visitors.

You can't do this using only client side technology (javascript, jquery etc) as every users request is independent from the last user. You need some form of persistence server side to count the visitors.

Comment: Sure, I understand the more complicated is the way to count visitor and so to start a popup
Anyway, if someone have an idea for how do that I will be happy ^^

Answer (score -1):

You can use localStorage (HTML5).
Like this:

```
if (localStorage.getItem("visit") == null) {
    alert("Show popup");
    localStorage.setItem("visit", "true"); //Set visit to true
}
```

Since it's HTML5 you can create a cookie callback using:

```
if (!localStorage) {
    var localStorage = {
        setItem: function(name, value) {
            var date = new Date();
                date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
                var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
            document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
        },

        getItem: function(name) {
            var nameEQ = name + "=";
            var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
            for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
                var c = ca[i];
                while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
                if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
}​
```

Comment: This is not what was asked for. It will only show one popup once for all visitors.

Comment: Okay, wel since English isn't my primary language I think I misonderstood.

Comment: Good script into html5 but that's not exactly what I need ^^'

Anyway thanks for your help